# Google Script using setValues timing out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a script that merges two spreadsheets with the same structure using setValues. It has started to time out recently because the data has become too large over time.

I did some research and stumbled upon [this website](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/10/12/benchmark-reading-and-writing-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/) which compares the performance of different read/write methods. The conclusion is that google's advanced services (Sheets API) can be used to save a significant amount of time over setValues.

I'm really struggling with how to convert my script to use SheetsAPI.  Here is my original code:

```
function getData() {
  var get_files = ['File1', 'File2'];
  var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('[ID for end result]').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  copySheet.getRange('A2:Z').clear();
  for (z = 0; z < get_files.length; z++) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`title='${get_files[z]}' and mimeType='${MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}' and trashed=false`);
    var file = files.hasNext() && files.next();
    if (!file) {
      console.log(`"${get_files[z]}" of Google Spreadsheet was not found.`);
      continue;
    }
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets();
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      var values = sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
      copySheet.getRange(copySheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
  }
}
```

I am not familar with Sheets API and I have tried to implement Range.copyTo with leverages SheetsAPI and uses less processing time.

Comment: A batchUpdate with Sheets API will probably be a lot faster

Comment: Although, Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual Spreadsheet from your question, I proposed a modified script using Sheets API. When you cannot obtain your expected situation from this script, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

When I saw your script, I thought that the Sheets API can be used for retrieving all values from all sheets from a Spreadsheet, and can be also used for putting all values to the destination sheet. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function getData() {
  var spreadsheetId = "[ID for end result]"; // Please set your destination spreadsheet ID.
  var get_files = ['File1', 'File2'];
  var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  copySheet.getRange('A2:Z').clear();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var values = [];
  for (z = 0; z < get_files.length; z++) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`title='${get_files[z]}' and mimeType='${MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}' and trashed=false`);
    var file = files.hasNext() && files.next();
    if (!file) {
      console.log(`"${get_files[z]}" of Google Spreadsheet was not found.`);
      continue;
    }
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets();
    var v = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(file.getId(), { ranges: sheets.map(s => s.getSheetName()) }).valueRanges.flatMap(({ values }) => values.slice(1));
    values = [...values, ...v];
  }
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values }, spreadsheetId, "Sheet1", { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
}
```

- When this script is run, all values from all sheets of 2 Spreadsheets of `['File1', 'File2']` are retrieved. And, the retrieved values are put to to "Sheet1" of the destination spreadsheet.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)